# How to install Python3.6.0 in centos automatically through shell scripts?

Tags: python-3.x, shell

I know clearly how to install python3.6 in centos step by step.How can I do it automatically through shell scripts?

Through step-by-step methods, I use

`tar -xvf python-file.tgz`

`./configure --prefix=/path/to/python3`

`make && make install`

to install python3.6 successfully. What I want to do is to write these commands into a shell script and install it automatically.

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# creat folder if not exists. That folder if the directory of Python3 programs.
if [ ! -d /usr/python3 ];then
    mkdir /usr/python3
else
    echo "'/usr/python3' exists"
fi

DIR=`pwd`
# extract file from compressed file to tartget directory
tar -xvf Python-3.6.0.tgz -C /usr 
# specify installation location
cd /usr/Python-3.6.0 && ./configure --prefix=/usr/python3 
# make file and install
cd /usr/Python-3.6.0 && make && make install

# creat symlink
ln -s /usr/python3/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3 
ln -s /usr/python3/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip3 
cd ${DIR} 
pip3 install --no-index --find-links=./pkgs -r ./requirements.txt
```

It seems that this script isn't run line by line because `/usr/python3` is empty, I want to know why.

Besides, I add `&& \` in each line except the last one, it seems works! I am really confused about it.